# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spectral'

Tags: modulenotfounderror

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "c:\Users\geode\under\root import.py", line 6, in <module>
    import spectral
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spectral'
```

I've tried `conda install -c conda-forge spectral` and checked the output of `conda list` to confirm that the `spectral` module is installed.

Output:

```
spectral    conda-forge/noarch::spectral-0.23.1-pyh1a96a4e_0
```

Comment: I just want to say thank you, for your precious time

Comment: solution -  do not run code but run Python file!!